# How to get a JavaDoc of a method at run time?

Tags: java, oop, runtime, javadoc

Its easy to get `a method Name` of a `Class` at run time
BUT
How i can get a `JavaDoc` of a method  at run time ?

As the following example

Our Class that include `JavaDoc` of our target method

```
public class MyClass {
    /**
     * 
     * @param x value of ....
     * @return result of ....
     */
    public String myMethod(int x) {
        return "any value";
    }

}
```

Our Class that has a main method

```
public class TestJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // get Class method Name at run time
        String methodName = MyClass.class.getMethods()[0].getName();
        System.out.println(methodName); // will print myMethod
        // How to  get a JavaDoc of myMethod `method` at run time
        // MyClass.class.getMethods()[0].????
        // expected to print a JavaDoc of myMethod
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "at run time"? The short answer is that you don't.

Comment: For what purpose? The user running the program almost certainly isn't a programmer: what good is showing him the Javadoc going to do?

Comment: This is actually a new [feature](http://sergiodelamo.es/preview-of-groovy-3/) for groovy 3. I could see this becoming a new way to provide documentation for rest api's. For instance using swagger.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't : the `class` file doesn't contain the comments.

A "solution" would be to generate the javadoc as HTML when you build your program and to build an URL from the name of the class and the name of the method. You could also generate the javadoc in a more suitable format than HTML using the [doclet API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html).

Comment: A nice "how-to" for using the doclet API is provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12872074/119259

Comment: See the custom annotations answer by Abhi. It offers an easier approach without requiring Internet.

Comment: @Johannes Except Abhi doesn't answer the question, which was about the javadoc, not other parts of the class...

Answer (score 25):

The only way to get it at runtime is to use custom annotations.

Create a custom annotation class:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(value = METHOD)
public @interface ServiceDef {
  /**
   * This provides description when generating docs.
   */
  public String desc() default "";
  /**
   * This provides params when generating docs.
   */
  public String[] params();
}
```

Use it on a method of a class, e.g.:

```
@ServiceDef(desc = "This is an utility class",
            params = {"name - the name","format - the format"})     
public void read(String name, String format)
```

Inspect the annotations via reflection:

```
for (Method method : Sample.class.getMethods()) {
  if (Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) {
    ServiceDef serviceDef = method.getAnnotation(ServiceDef.class);
    if (serviceDef != null) {
      String[] params = serviceDef.params();
      String descOfMethod = serviceDef.desc();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you provide an example pls?

Comment: the biggest problem is still having to sync/maintain both javadoc and the annotation string constant

Comment: I would recommend two separate Annotations, maybe @ Params and @ Brief

Answer (score 20):

Annotation processors have access to the Javadoc comments in the source code. If you have control over the compilation process for the classes whose Javadoc you are interested in, you can use an annotation processor to grab the Javadoc at compile-time and make it available later at runtime.

This is the approach used in the [therapi-runtime-javadoc](https://github.com/dnault/therapi-runtime-javadoc) project (disclosure: which I authored and am shamelessly plugging).

Comment: An interesting approach.  Now a bit later do you have experiences from production?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen It has been working fine in the [therapi-json-rpc](https://github.com/dnault/therapi-json-rpc) project. As for lessons learned, version 0.4.0 stores the Javadoc in JSON class path resources instead of generated Java classes. This produces smaller JARs and is kinder to the class loader. The annotation processor and runtime library are now separate artifacts for more flexibility. This is one of my passion projects, and I try to respond to [issues](https://github.com/dnault/therapi-runtime-javadoc/issues) quickly.

Comment: Hi @dnault, is it also possible to access javadoc warnings and errors using that approach? Fx a Link to another class, but with a spelling error. IDEs will highlight stuff like that but I haven't found a way to access it by AbstractProcessor and visitors/scanners. I am using this guide/example: https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/openjdk-8/langtools/test/tools/javac/diags/DocCommentProcessor.java.shtml

Comment: @Hervian I don't think it would help you with that. If you do discover a portable way to access the imports so that you can validate links, I'd love to hear about it :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can [run javadoc programmatically](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/standard-doclet.html#runningprogrammatically) and passing options to generate documentation for the class that you want and then parsing the generated document to get the documentation for the method that you want. You will need the source code at runtime because comments are not in the class file.

Comment: having a hard time to find a command line for this.. even to run from within the application :/

Answer (score 3):

Comments do not have a representation in bytecode, they get stripped out by the compiler and aren't available "at runtime".