# Extracting Javadoc @version tag at runtime

Tags: version, javadoc

Is there a neat way of getting the Javadoc `@version` at runtime?

I have an "overview.html" file that contains the application version that I would like to print onto the GUI that's part of the application. I could just read this file and extract it that way, but I'm wondering if there's a smarter way to do it?

Comment: I think that's smart enough according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312238/how-to-get-a-javadoc-of-a-method-at-run-time

Comment: Certainly seems that way. I'm not as au fait with Java as other languages, so I wasn't sure if there was some wizardry that you could do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going with this the answer to the question found by Balazs.