# Is there a way to get the jdk version where the class came

Tags: java, version

in Java, I want to know if there is a way to get the jdk version where a class have been added, I want a function that outputs "14" when I put in argument the `RecordComponent` class (*`java.lang.reflect.RecordComponent`*). 
`ArrayList` outputs "7" etc

Is there a way to make something like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is stored in the `@since` tag in the javadoc of the class.

To get this information for a specific class you could use the package [jdk.javadoc.doclet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.javadoc/jdk/javadoc/doclet/package-summary.html)

Comment: Okay but I have to do this in runtime, not with a command in a terminal, is there a way to do this so ?

Comment: As explained in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15312267/5948314 The class does not contain comments. This makes it very difficult to acces them runtime. 
The easiest solution is probably to scrape the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/RecordComponent.html)